# disable lowercase of facet fields in solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search, faceted-search

I'm using solr 3.5 and added a custom field, which adds a category to a document by defining the following in schema.xml.

```
<field name="category" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Now I'm implementing a Search-Web-Client, which should display all values of the index of that category field. I did that with the following query:

```
facet=true&facet.field=category&q=*
```

The results look like:

```
<response>
 <lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">45</int>
  <lst name="params">
   <str name="facet.field">category</str>
   <str name="q">*</str>
   <str name="facet">true</str>
  </lst>
 </lst>
 <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" maxScore="0.0"/>
  <lst name="facet_counts">
  <lst name="facet_queries"/>
  <lst name="facet_fields">
  <lst name="category">
   <int name="category1">0</int>
   <int name="category2">0</int>
   <int name="category3">0</int>
   <int name="category4">0</int>
   <int name="category5">0</int>
  </lst>
 </lst>
 <lst name="facet_dates"/>
  <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
  </lst>
</response>
```

My Web-Client displays all names of categories, but they are written in lowercase, but are stored in the index with capital letter.

```
<response>
 <result>
  <doc>
   ...
   <str name="category">Category1</str>
   ...
  </doc>
 </result>
</response>
```

- Solution a: Is it possible to force the facet-values names to be case-sensitive?
- Solution b: Is there another query which will give every value of category stored in the index?

Comment: Can you please post the definition of your string fieldType in your `schema.xml`? It isn't the default one, right?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is the default definition. But I needed to reindex my sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect you're using a `LowerCaseFilterFactory` for your field of type `string`. In that case, the indexed values is `category1` but the stored value is still the original you submitted, `Category1`.

You should just remove the `LowerCaseFilterFactory` from the `string` fieldType definition in your `schema.xml` to have the desired facet behaviour.

In fact, it's common to use specific copyField for facet with simple fieldType, without `Tokenizer`, `Filter` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the type from text_general (which has a LowerCaseFilterFactory) to string. String doesn't have such a filter. I forgot to delete the index and reindex my webpages. After that everything worked fine.